# Using "source" to set up aliases in WSL 2 using Ubuntu and tcsh

Tags: linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, tcsh

I am exploring the use of WSL 2 for Windows 10, version 2004. My preferred shell is tcsh, which I've installed. I am now trying to set up my usual aliases by placing them in a file such as .tschrc that is read when I start the terminal program under Ubuntu. However, this approach is consistently failing. I have traced this back to problems "source-ing" a file with the "source" command.

For example, suppose .tcshrcSAV2 contains this line:

```
alias ll 'ls -l'
```

If I use the source command on this file like so:

```
source .tcshrcSAV2
```

I get an error and the alias does not work. The error after executing the source command is:

```
: Command not found.
```

The problem is not the source command. It is found and executed. If I do "which source", it is indeed the built-in shell command.

Some sort of alias is created, but it does not work. If I execute the command

```
ll
```

I get the following error:

```
's: invalid option -- '
Try 'ls --help' for more information.
```

If I list the aliases in my shell, it looks OK:

```
$> alias
ll      ls -l
```

However, there is clearly something wrong with the alias. If instead I create the alias at the command line, and not through sourcing the file above, the alias works.

Is this a known problem with tcsh on WSL 2? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying on a normal Linux system, it works as usual.

Still on a *native* Linux system *bash* shell, typing (without ending the line):

```
ls -l
```

and then adding <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>m</kbd> to insert a [CR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) character and validating the line gives OP's error. Editing the file and adding a trailing CR byte so it ends in CRLF - Windows style - instead of LF - Unix/Linux - style gets the same error once sourced in *tcsh*.

What happens is that `ls` is asked to use an option with the "letter" CR which isn't a known option. It's displayed back as an additional CR, thus putting back the last `'` in place of the `l` of `ls` on the same first line of the error displayed.

So I can only deduce that the tool used to edit the file created a line ending in CRLF instead of the expected LF. Perhaps the tool wasn't itself running within WSL. Or perhaps it's related to the terminal interface.

You should probably use `vi` to create this file (editing it when it's already having CRLFs will still make it tell it kept the `[dos]` format). So if that's not enough you can still do for example this to remove the trailing CR character:

```
tr -d '\r' < .tcshrcSAV2 > .tcshrcSAV3
source .tcshrcSAV3
```

Comment: The origin of this is probably that the content came from a native Windows file originally. I have been using vi to edit it, but there must have been CR in that is invisible and persisted through the vi edit sessions.